# Function not invoking and changing background color on mouseover

Tags: javascript, css, mouseover

I have populated a container with grids and now want to add functionality whereby when your mouse goes over the cells the background colour changes.

So far I have:

```
let container = document.getElementById("container");

let createGrid = (row, col) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < (row * col); i++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.className = ("cell");
    container.appendChild(cell);
  }
}
createGrid(100, 60);

let cells = document.querySelectorAll('container div');
let functionality = () => cells.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  cells.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
);
functionality();
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using CSS `:hover`?

Comment: Need the background color to stay until cleared, creating the clear function is the next step :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not correctly targeting the `<div>` elements in your `querySelectorAll`. Also, `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` object that consists of all the div elements that you queried so you have to loop through each element in the NodeList using a method like [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and then apply the style to each element.

---

Check and run the following Code Snippet for a practical example of the above approach:

```js
let container = document.getElementById("container");

let createGrid = (row, col) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < (row * col); i++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.className = ("cell");
    container.appendChild(cell);
  }
}
createGrid(100, 60);

let cells = document.querySelectorAll('#container div');
let functionality = () => cells.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
));
functionality();
```

```css
.cell {padding: 5px;}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

---

**N.B.** Instead of targeting all `<div>` elements inside `#container`, you can target all the div elements with the class name "cell" since you have added that class name to each grid element and that would prevent unwanted css changes to other types of `<div>` elements that you might add to `#container` in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do anything else when hovering you can just apply CSS like this:

```
.cell:hover{
  background-color: red;
}
```

If you want to do this whit JavaScript you need to iterate over the cells and add the listener for each cell:

```
for(var i=0;i<cells.length;i++){
  cells[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

The color on hovering will not stay, if you do it with JavaScript the red background color will stay after leaving the cell.